# Floating div (changeing top attr) is not smooth

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

I tried to write some simply floating div. On event scroll() I'm changeing the top position (while floating div have position relative). Everything is fine on new FF, but on older version such as FF 5, or on IE 8, when scrolling page, the effect is not smooth.

I prepared a demo on jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/BzHjk/

It is very simply and I have no idea why it's not floating smoothly. :/

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at using position: fixed; instead of js.

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/position.html

http://jsfiddle.net/BzHjk/4/

Comment: Thanks, for answer, but I'm going to do some floating div with boundaries. I know solution that inside boundaries I can use position fixed and outside boundaries I can use position relative to stop floating. But I'm realy curious why my example is not smooth? Its depend on javascript speed in browser like FF5 or IE8?

Comment: Most likely javascript improvements from FF5 to FF10. You could use jQuery's animate to make it smooth but there would be a delay.